# Implicit declaration of function in main/error:expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant|

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "simpio.h"

#define cols 10
#define rows 10

void populate_data(int rows,int cols,int A[rows][cols],int R,int C);
void print_array(int rows,int cols,int A[rows][cols],int R,int C);
void change_array(int rows,int cols,int A[rows][cols],int R,int C);

int main(){
    
int R,C,A[rows][cols];

/*Eisagwgh twn grammwn/sthlwn*/
printf("Dwse ton arithmo twn grammwn: ");
R=GetInteger();
printf("Dwse ton arithmo twn sthlwn: ");
C=GetInteger();

populate_data(rows,cols,A,R,C);
printf("ARXIKOS PINAKAS");
print_array(rows,cols,A,R,C);
change_array(rows,cols,A,R,C);
printf("ALLAGMENOS PINAKAS");
print_array(rows,cols,A,R,C);

return 0;

}


void populate_data(int rows,int cols,int A[rows][cols],int R,int C){

int i,j;

for (i=0; i<R; i++){
    for (j=0; j<C; j++){
        A[i][j]=rand()%100;
    }
}

}
void print_array(int rows,int cols,int A[rows][cols],int R,int C){

int i,j;

for (i=0; i<R; i++){
        printf("\n");
    for (j=0; j<C; j++){
        printf("%d",A[i][j]);
    }
}
}
void change_array(int rows,int cols,int A[rows][cols],int R,int C){

int i,j,index,max;

for (i=0; i<R; i++){
        max=A[i][0];
        index=0;
    for (j=1; j<C; j++){
        if (A[i][j]>max){
            max=A[i][j];
            index=j;
        }
    }
    for (j=0; j<index; j++){
        A[i][j]=max;
    }
}

}
```

So I just wrote this code for a project at my university. When I compile it, it says "Implicit declaration of function ", but the lines where the error occured are these: "populate_data(rows,cols,A,R,C);
print_array(rows,cols,A,R,C);
change_array(rows,cols,A,R,C);". Also, it says "error:expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant|." at the #define lines. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `cols` and `rows` preprocessor constants are conflicting with the `cols` and `rows` variables. You can't use the same names for both. The preprocessor is replacing all the occurrences with `10`, yielding this syntactically invalid code:

```
void populate_data(int 10,int 10,int A[10][10],int R,int C);
void print_array(int 10,int 10,int A[10][10],int R,int C);
void change_array(int 10,int 10,int A[10][10],int R,int C);
```

I advise always using uppercase for preprocessor macros. That's the norm in C to make it obvious which identifiers are macros.

```
#define COLS 10
#define ROWS 10
```